# Connect javascript file with django in static file

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

### Solved - problem was in django and js file. After repair django i don't check console in my Web browser which show issue in on js file. THank you everyone for help.

Update - refresh content of files after changes

I attach a js file to my Django but have problem bcz JS don't works on website view, when CSS file style Django see. I try looks some toturial but still the same problem. Arrow etc don;t react on any click.

settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

import dotenv

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

dotenv.load_dotenv()

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG") == "True"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'turbineweb',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Turbine_power_Web.urls'
'''
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
'''
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'staticfiles': 'django.templatetags.static',
            }
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Turbine_power_Web.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../turbineweb/static')]

#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home_page'

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home_page'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

urls.py in project

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('turbineweb.urls')),
]
```

urls.py in app

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

template:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Turbine Power Web </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="TurbinePowerWeb let u choose turbine model adding by turbine manufacturer
        and check their energy production in a given period of time"/>
        <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <section>
                        <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark ">
              <!-- Container wrapper -->
              <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center">
                <!-- Navbar brand -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home/"> Turbine Power Web</a>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/password-change/">Change Password</a></li>
                        
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Turbine Models</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Author</a></li>
                        
                            <li class="nav-item"> Hello, Tester </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </section>
    
        <div class="bg">
        
    <main>
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="top-row">
                <img class="arrow left-class" id="arrow-left" src="/static/image/arrow-left.png" />
                <div id="slides-container">
                    <img class="slide active" src="/static/image/about-us.png">
                    <img class="slide" src="/static/image/turbine-models.png">
                    <img class="slide" src="/static/image/calculate-power.png">
                </div>
                <img class="arrow right-class" id="arrow-right" src="/static/image/arrow-right.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-row">
                <div id="dots">
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/static/js/home_page.js"></script>
    </main>

    </body>
</html>
```

js file:

```
let activeSlideNumber = 1;
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left')
let arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right')

let hideActiveSlide = () => {
    let activeElement = document.querySelector('.active');
    activeElement.classList.remove('active')
}

let showSlide = (slideNumber) => {
    hideActiveSlide();
    document.querySelector('#slide'+slideNumber).classList.add('active')
}

let showNextSlide = () => {
    if(activeSlideNumber === 3) {
        activeSlideNumber = 1;
    } else {
        activeSlideNumber = activeSlideNumber + 1;
    }
    showSlide(activeSlideNumber);
};

let showPreviousSlide = () => {
    if(activeSlideNumber === 1) {
        activeSlideNumber = 3;
    } else {
        activeSlideNumber = activeSlideNumber - 1;
    }
    showSlide(activeSlideNumber);
};

for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    let showSlideI = () => {
        activeSlideNumber = 1;
        showSlide(i)
    };
    document.querySelector('#dol'+i).addEventListener('click', showSlideI);
}

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', showNextSlide);
arrowRight.addEventListener('click', showPreviousSlide);
```

Projecy view:

- Turbine_power_Web (project)

  - settings.py
  - urls.py
- accounts (app)
- turbineweb(app)

  - static

    - css

      - style.css
    - image

      - images.png
    - js

      - home_page.js
    - templates
    - turbineweb

      - home_page.html
    - init.py
    - admin.py
    - models.py
  - urls.py
- manage.py

on Terminal get error:

```
    WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\Dom\Desktop\Python_Project\django_proejct_magisterka\Turbine_power_Web\../turbineweb/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you also configured the settings in urls.py or not? Share project's urls.py.

Comment: was `sttatic` a typo in your project structure?

Comment: i don't configure settings in urls.py

Comment: yes "stattic" was a typo in project structure

Comment: Have you configured `STATICFILES_STORAGE` in your `settings.py`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATICFILES_STORAGE and have you ran `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: I don't configurate STATICFILES_STORAGE (i try rn). Run *python manage.py collectstatic* give me : - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: I add in settings.py - **STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')** and after run *python manage.py collectstati* get: 135 static files copied to 'C:\Users\Dom\Desktop\Python_Project\django_proejct_magisterka\Turbine_power_Web\static'. - website still don't see js

Comment: First configure `STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]` in your `settings.py` and try again. I think `collectstatic` is only needed if you're deploying your app without the `manage.py runserver`

Comment: I add **STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]** in settings (needed remove Static_ROOT but thats not help

Comment: I update main post and refresh content of files after changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. We were looking at the wrong place. Your Django settings are correct. It's your js file which selects the wrong button:

Change:

```
let arrowLeft = document.querySelector('.arrow-left')
let arrowRight = document.querySelector('.arrow-right')
```

To:

```
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left')
let arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right')
```

### Edit

I took a closer look at your js file and found some missing selectors.

I've added **id="sliderX"** and **id="dotX"**. Without them your js threw an error and was never executed.

```
<main>
    <div id="slider">
        <div id="top-row">
            <img class="arrow left-class" id="arrow-left" src="/static/image/arrow-left.png" />
            <div id="slides-container">
                <img class="slide active" id="slide1" src="/static/image/about-us.png">
                <img class="slide" id="slide2" src="/static/image/turbine-models.png">
                <img class="slide" id="slide3" src="/static/image/calculate-power.png">
            </div>
            <img class="arrow right-class" id="arrow-right" src="/static/image/arrow-right.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-row">
            <div id="dots">
                <div class="dot" id="dot1"></div>
                <div class="dot" id="dot2"></div>
                <div class="dot" id="dot3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/static/js/home_page.js"></script>
</main>
```

I didn't change your js other then the change I mentioned at the top of this post.

*Sidenote: Rightclick in your Chrome Browser > Inspect and then at the top of the Sidebar click of "Console". Here you will see all js erros including reference for debugging.*

Comment: I think this is not the problem

Comment: I change but that doesn't help

Comment: But the js seems to load corretly `[06/Oct/2022 11:11:50] "GET /static/js/home_page.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1167` . Try to debug your js. I'll take a look later if I have some time

Comment: I update main post and refresh content of files after changes

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
 <script src="{% static 'js/home_page.js' %}"></script>
```

try this:

```
<script src="{% static '/js/home_page.js' %}"></script>
```

And correct your typo sttatic to static

In settings file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Also in TEMPLATES in settings file, add it:

```
'libraries' : {
                'staticfiles': 'django.templatetags.static', 
            }
```

EX:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries' : {
                'staticfiles': 'django.templatetags.static', #Added here
            }
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: `<script src="{% static 'js/home_page.js' %}"></script>` should be the correct syntax if the `settings.py` settings are correct

Comment: i try but still js don't works. I add in settings **STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'* but thats not help

Comment: I copy ur change but it not solve this problem

Comment: In your templates, instead of this {% load static %} do this {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: change on  {% load staticfiles %} but thats still not help

Comment: I think your static folder in wrong direction try to move that inside your django project not inside your django app

Comment: I try and move into project but thats not help

Comment: please provide your whole settings.py file and template. I will checkout.

Comment: I update main post and refresh content of files after changes @ManojTolagekar

Comment: why you added multiple TEMPLATES in settings.py file? just need only one

Comment: looks  your structure of static folder, this is not the way you do

Comment: js folder must inside static folder not insdie css folder

Comment: after moving static folder inside django project, you have to remove your django app from here STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../turbineweb/static')]. try this STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

Comment: this js and image in css folder that was  a typo here

Comment: change on **STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]**  and still get: *?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\Dom\Desktop\Python_Project\django_proejct_magisterka\Turbine_power_Web\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.*

Answer (score -1):

in my urls.py i configurate static but thats not help - answering on Sunderam Dubey comment

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

---

after add in setttings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]
```

needed to remove STATIC_ROOT

---

Ctrl + U give me it:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Turbine Power Web </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="TurbinePowerWeb let u choose turbine model adding by turbine manufacturer
        and check their energy production in a given period of time"/>
        <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <section>
                        <!-- Navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark ">
              <!-- Container wrapper -->
              <div class="container-fluid justify-content-center">
                <!-- Navbar brand -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home/"> Turbine Power Web</a>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/password-change/">Change Password</a></li>
                        
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Turbine Models</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Author</a></li>
                        
                            <li class="nav-item"> Hello, Tester </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </section>
    
        <div class="bg">
        
    <main>
        <div id="slider">
            <div id="top-row">
                <img class="arrow left-class" id="arrow-left" src="/static/image/arrow-left.png" />
                <div id="slides-container">
                    <img class="slide active" src="/static/image/about-us.png">
                    <img class="slide" src="/static/image/turbine-models.png">
                    <img class="slide" src="/static/image/calculate-power.png">
                </div>
                <img class="arrow right-class" id="arrow-right" src="/static/image/arrow-right.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="bottom-row">
                <div id="dots">
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="/static/js/home_page.js"></script>
    </main>



        </div>
            

            
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is only used to store static file but here we need to load the static files

Comment: Delete this answer as it not answers the question, it is considered as NAA(Not an Answer).

Comment: i add in settings: **STATIC_URL = '/static/'**

**STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]** - thats not help. What u mean by load static files ?

Comment: @Robson Press ctrl+U to see source code and click on script tag's file to see whether file is opening or not, I mean it is attached or not.

Comment: Click on `<script src="/static/js/home_page.js"></script>` and see it opens or not, after Ctrl+U.

Comment: Yes thats open @SunderamDubey

Comment: @Robson That's mean it should load, why it doesn't?

Comment: @Robson At last, I'd recommend you to hard refresh the page using `ctrl+f5` and run server in another port using `python manage.py runserver 5000`.

Comment: I try  refresh page and use other port but that doesn't help

Comment: I update main post and refresh content of files after changes